# Creating an index using transactional data

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a dataset of a series of leases.

Variables we have: **precinct**, **date** (in quarters), **lettable area**, **price** as well as a few others.

These assets are not homogenous, although are comparable.

In some periods, the data is quite dense, where we have multiple entries for each precinct-date combination, at other times, we can go a couple of quarters without an entry.

I am trying to derive a market price based on these leases. Fue to the sparseness of data, looking at period-on-period changes like a typical index won't work.

**What would be a good approach to deriving that market price?**

Comment: I'm increasingly thinking that a decent approach would be to create a hedonic index.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches here to derive an index.

- **Repeat Sales Index**- Comparing changes in a value over time. The advantage of this is that because it is a repeat transaction, you know it is comparable. It doesn't need to be a sale, just a value.
- **Hedonic Price Index** - Which looks at price changes accounting for various including locational and quality based.
- **Random Forest** - A machine learning approach.

The [hpiR packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hpiR/vignettes/introduction.html) has worked examples in its vingette.